# Error with flask-login

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, flask-login

I have difficulty in using the Flask-Login framework for authentication. I have looked through the documentation as thoroughly as possible but apparently I am missing something obvious.

```
class User():
    def __init__(self, userid=None, username=None, password=None):
        self.userid = userid
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True

    def is_active(self):
        return True

    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False

    def get_id(self):
        return unicode(self.userid)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username

def find_by_username(username):
    try:
        data = app.mongo.db.users.find_one_or_404({'username': username})

        user = User()
        user.userid = data['_id']
        user.username = data['username']
        user.password = data['password']
        return user

    except HTTPException:
        return None


def find_by_id(userid):
    try:
        data = app.mongo.db.users.find_one_or_404({'_id': userid})
        user = User(data['_id'], data['username'], data['password'])
        return user

    except HTTPException:
        return None
```

The above is my User class located in `users/models.py`

```
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'users.login'

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(userid):
return find_by_id(userid)
```

The above is my user loader.

```
@mod.route('/login/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        pw_hash = hashlib.md5(form.password.data).hexdigest()
        user = find_by_username(form.username.data)
        if user is not None:
            if user.password == pw_hash:
                if login_user(user):
                    flash('Logged in successfully.')
                    return redirect(request.args.get('next') or url_for('users.test'))
                else:
                    flash('Error')

        else:
            flash('Username or password incorrect')

    else:
        flash('Username or password incorrect')

return render_template('users/login.html', form=form)
```

There is no apparently error message, but when trying to access any views decorated with `@login_required`, it redirects me to the login form. Best as I can tell, the `login_user` function isn't actually working although it returns `True` when I called it. Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After stepping through a debugger for a while, I finally fixed the problem.

The key issue is that I was attempting to use the `_id` parameter from the MongoDB collection as the userid. I did not realize that the `_id` parameter was an `ObjectID` type instead of a string or unicode which I needed.

```
def find_by_username(username):
    try:
        data = app.mongo.db.users.find_one_or_404({'username': username})

        user = User(unicode(data['_id']), data['username'], data['password'])
        return user

    except HTTPException:
        return None


def find_by_id(userid):
    try:
        data = app.mongo.db.users.find_one_or_404({'_id': ObjectId(userid)})
        user = User(unicode(data['_id']), data['username'], data['password'])
        return user
```

Modifying the two functions appropriately fixed this error.

Answer (score 1):

If you've verified it's not your `login_user` function, then that leaves your `find_by_id` function.

The source code for the `user_loader` says:

> The function you set should take a user ID (a `unicode`) and return a user object, or `None` if the user does not exist.

Your `find_by_id` function uses `find_one_or_404` which raises an eyebrow.  I'd add some extra debugging around that function, add some prints, or logging to show it's being called, with the correct unicode id, and that it's returning a `User` object, or `None`.

Hopefully that'll get you closer to narrowing down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to find the place where you assign the user_id to the session after validating the form:

```
session['user_id'] = form.user.id
```

Have a look at this [SimpleRegistrationForm](https://github.com/marchon/Flask-Simple-Registration/blob/master/flaskext/simpleregistration.py) on Github as an example