# Flask-Login User is Anonymous even after successful login

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication, flask, flask-login

I've gone through all the questions in stackoverflow regarding the login problems in flask-login. However, in all the scenarios the DB used is either postgresql, sqlite etc. I'm using MongoDB in my flask app. Please ignore password encryption/hashing etc.

Similar questions : 
[Error with flask-login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082933/error-with-flask-login?rq=1)
and many more but cannot find anything valuable.

Current code for **User** class

```
class User(UserMixin):
def __init__(self, id, user_name):
    self.id = id
    self.user_name = user_name
    self.active = True

def is_authenticated(self):
    return True

def is_active(self):
    return self.is_active

def is_anonymous(self):
    return False

def get_id(self):
    return self.id
```

code sample for **user_loader**.

```
@loginManager.user_loader
def loadUser(user_id):
    reg_user = db.users.find_one({'_id': user_id})
    if reg_user:
        user = User(user_id, reg_user['userName'])
        if user_id == user.get_id():
            return user
    return None
```

code sample for **Login** method

```
def login():
    user_name = request.form['user_name']
    pass_word = request.form['pass_word']

    if user_name and pass_word:
        registered_user = db.users.find_one(user_name, pass_word)
        if registered_user:
            user = User(str(registered_user['_id']), user_name)
            login_user(user)      ## This is returning True
            return jsonify({
                "result": "success",
                "message": "Logged In !!",
                "name": user.user_name    ## correctly set to expected user_name
            })
        else:
            return jsonify({
                "result": "Failed",
                "message": "User doesn't exist."
            })
    else: ...
```

I'm getting proper results with the jsonify response. But whenever I'm redirecting to a view decorated with "**@login_required**", the user is redirected to login page. current user object is set but the trace logs showing anonymous UserMixin. What might be possibly wrong here ?

Comment: I don't entirely understand part `user = User(user_id, reg_user['userName'])`. Why do you create a new User object?

Comment: Thanks for finding that out. I almost spent a day on flask-login. I removed the  new user creation from the loadUser function and it all worked fine. Returning the reg_user instead. But as many times as I go through the documentation, I can't understand what the loadUser function does, _when is it triggered_  , How is the current user set etc. ? A small description would be much helpful.

Comment: `flask-login` is not a complicated module, decorator `@lm.user_loader` is just a simple callback function which is later triggered in [`_load_user()`](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/blob/master/flask_login/login_manager.py#L298) method. Just have a look at the source code and it should clear things up for you.